# How to exit the loop in pry

Tags: ruby, pry

If you keep type 'n',

you will  be in the loop  for 100 times,

How could I leave the each loop and continue to keep debugging from line 7 without exiting the loop then run the remain code automatically,

The behavior of `exit` `!!!` are not suit for me,
Because I want to keep debugging the code after I exit the loop.

```
    1: require 'pry'
    2:
 => 3: binding.pry
    4: (1..100).each do |x|
    5:     print x
    6: end
    7:
    8: print "hi"
```

Comment: You need to use `break` inside `each`.

Comment: @ArupRakshit [1] pry(main)> break
SyntaxError: (eval):2: Can't escape from eval with break

Comment: did you tried `gem install pry-nav` and using `continue` ?

Comment: you are not using `binding.pry` in the loop... and if it is used in the loop `exit` would move you to the next iteration, while `!!!` would take you out of pry completely

Comment: @ymonad use the `continue` won't be stopped at `line 8`

Comment: you should add another `binding.pry` at `line 8`

Comment: It's not practical to trace other projects when you wanna exit a loop by inserting another `binding.pry`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `gem install pry-debugger` (if you have installed pry-nav you may uninstall it at first).When you come here:

```
    1: require 'pry'
    2: 
 => 3: binding.pry
    4: (1..100).each do |x|
    5:   print x
    6: end
    7: 
    8: print "hi"
```

Set a breakpoint at `line 8` by using `break 8`:

```
[2] pry(main)> break 8
Breakpoint 1: /home/darfux/Desktop/ruby/STO/23622590.rb @ line 8 (Enabled) :

    5:   print x
    6: end
    7: 
 => 8: print "hi"
```

Then type `continue` to continue the program and it will hit the breakpoint at `line 8`:

```
[3] pry(main)> continue
123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990919293949596979899100
Breakpoint 1. First hit.

From: /home/darfux/Desktop/ruby/STO/23622590.rb @ line 8 :

    3: binding.pry
    4: (1..100).each do |x|
    5:   print x
    6: end
    7: 
 => 8: print "hi"

[4] pry(main)>
```

See more [here](https://github.com/nixme/pry-debugger)

Answer (score 20):

you can use `disable-pry` command